Proving an Identity on Certain Second Derivative of a Function on a Lie Group
Let $G$ be a Lie group, $\mathfrak{g}$ its Lie algebra, and take $X\in \mathfrak{g}$ and $f\in C^\infty(G)$.
Pick a basis $(E_i)_{i=1}^n$ for $\mathfrak{g}$, and define $\partial_k(f\circ\exp)$ to be the $k$th partial derivative with respect to this basis. Also write $X=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i E_i$.
I would like to prove or disprove the following:
$$
\sum_{i,j=1}^n\partial_i\partial_j(f\circ \exp) X_i X_j = (XXf)_e
$$
Attempt:
In the special case $G=\mathrm{GL}(N)$, we can just compute both sides directly (since here $\mathfrak{g}$ consists of matrices, I write $X_{ij}$ instead of $X_i$ and so on, $\partial_{ij}$ then denotes derivative with respect to the $ij$th entry; summation convention is used):
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\mathrm{RHS} = X_e \Big(g\mapsto\frac{d}{dt}\Big|_{t=0}f(ge^{tX})\Big) = X_e \Big(g\mapsto (gX)_{ij} \partial_{ij} f(g)\Big)\\
&=\frac{d}{dt}\Big|_{t=0}(e^{tX} X)_{ij}\partial_{ij}f(e^{tX})
= (XX)_{ij}\partial_{ij} f(\mathbb{1})
+ X_{ij} X_{kl}\partial_{ij}\partial_{kl}f(\mathbb{1})
\end{aligned}
$$
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\mathrm{LHS} = X_{ij}X_{kl}\partial_{ij}\partial_{kl}(f\circ \exp)=X_{ij}X_{kl}\partial_{ij}[(\partial_{ab}f\circ \exp)\partial_{kl}\exp_{ab}]\\
&= X_{ij}X_{kl}\Big[(\partial_{cd}\partial_{ab}f\circ \exp)\cdot \partial_{kl}\exp_{ab}\partial_{ij}\exp_{cd} + (\partial_{ab}f\circ \exp)\partial_{ij}\partial_{kl}\exp_{ab}\Big]_{0}\\
&=X_{cd}X_{ab}\partial_{cd}\partial_{ab}f(\mathbb{1})
+(XX)_{ab}\partial_{ab}f(\mathbb{1}),
\end{aligned}
$$
where I used $\partial_{ij}\exp_{cd}\Big|_0 = \delta_{ic}\delta_{jd}$ and $\partial_{ij}\partial_{kl}\exp_{ab}X\Big|_0 X_{ij}X_{kl} = (XX)_{ab}$.
I think this calculation generalizes to any matrix group, but I have no idea how to prove this in the most general setting (where $G$ is a Lie group).
